# RAILS 6 : How to run rails tasks in crontab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I wuould like to run rails tasks started by cron (crontab entry).
But I get always the error that the rails command could not be found.

```
/bin/sh: rails: No such file or directory
```

So what I tried is the same as the .profile or .bashrs contains :

```
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

It dont know which variables need to be exported, or which programm/tools/sub-command need to be execuuted before, in which order, first execute command XYZ then export GEM___ variable 1 2 3, then execute another sub-command, then check by command ABC but not when tool rvm list returns string not equal RVM_string_1 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem for this. Please follow these bellow steps:

**Step 1:** Add whenever gem into your Gemfile

```
# Gemfile

gem 'whenever', '~> 1.0'
```

**Step 2:** Run `bundle install` to install this gem.

**Step 3:** Run `wheneverize .` This will create an initial `config/schedule.rb` file for you (as long as the config folder is already present in your project).

**Step 4:** Open newly created `config/schedule.rb` and write your scheduler task.

```
# config/schedule.rb
# here `fetch_user_meetings:sync` this is one task in my case.
# please replace this with your task.

every :hour do
  rake "fetch_user_meetings:sync", output: {
    error: 'log/fetch_user_meetings_sync_error.log',
    standard: 'log/fetch_user_meetings_sync_access.log'
  }
end
```

**Step 5:** Run `whenever`. This command will output a preview of the generated schedules in the actual cron format and attach your job with crontab. Whenever you are modifying your `config/scheduler.rb`, run this command. This will update your cron job.

**NB:** There are many options to set your scheduler job. Please follow this [doc](https://github.com/javan/whenever#example-schedulerb-file).

Happy Coding :-)